# I can't identify what is happening in this table with a PDF on it

Tags: sql-server-2012, filestream

I have a table with this config:

[image]

Now if you look at COLUMN_11, it is a varchar -1.

But as far as I know, to insert a PDF file into a table, you need filestream, and the column should be VARBINARY(max) right?

so, how is this working? why is there a PDF in a VARCHAR column?

the DocumentBody is this:

[image]

Obviously theres millions of this one.

Comment: How do you or somebody else inserts rows in this table?

Comment: Filestream is not required to insert data into MAX types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you see `-1` as the value for a `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` data type, that is just a numeric representation for `MAX` for the [.NET SQLDBTYPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/modifying-large-value-max-data?redirectedfrom=MSDN) as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1713977/5059085).

So it looks like the application probably just stores the serialized encoded string representation of the PDF in the database in a `VARCHAR(MAX)` column then.

I assume the developer who designed this thought it was the *easiest* way to store the PDF, as opposed to `VARBINARY(MAX)`, which would save you space (as Dan Guzman notes in the comments). Additionally it's actually best practice to not store files themselves in the database, but rather on a file system somewhere, and store the location reference to that file in the database instead.

Comment: Specifically, the value looks to be base64 encoded string of the original binary value. IMHO, it would be better to store the raw value as varbinary(MAX) to save space.

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes probably so. Likely the developer behind the app wasn't aware of this and choosing VARCHAR was the *easiest* solution they knew of, so they went with it, I'm guessing.

Comment: Tahnks guys this is what I was thinking too. it was easier at the time, so lets do it.